# Taylor expansion term equals zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential

I have to Taylor expand an effective potential $U_{eff}$, which is given by:

$$U_{eff}(r)=-\frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{r}+\frac{l^{2}}{2\mu r^{2}}$$

I then expand it and get:

$$U_{eff}(r)=U_{eff}(r_{min})+\frac{dU_{eff}}{dr}\bigg|_{r=r_{min}}(r-r_{min}) +\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^{2}U_{eff}}{dr^{2}}\bigg|_{r=r_{min}}(r-r_{min})^{2} + \dots$$

Now, according to my book, it says that the 2nd term equals zero, or at least the derivative term of the 2nd term is. But it doesn't say why, so I'm kinda confused as why this is ? Is it some basic stuff I have forgotten, or is it something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are expanding around a minimum, the derivative is zero by definition. Recall how you find the extrema of a function: the condition
$$\frac{df}{dr}=0$$
gives you $r_{\text{min}}$, around which you can then expand.